# As3 How to remove or update bitmapdata for a new level?

Tags: actionscript-3, new-operator, bitmapdata

I'm making a maze game. The character can't walk through the walls of the maze (because of a collition detection between the bitmapdata from the character and the bmd from the walls). When the character arrives at a door, the next level/frame should appear with a new maze (new bounds)

For the next level (next frame), I made a new maze with different walls. But the bitmapdata from the first maze is still 'active'. So even though there's a new maze, the bitmapdata from the previous walls is invisible but still drawn on the stage.

My question to you is:
I want to change the bounds/maze every frame, how can I remove the previous bitmapdata so the character won't walk through the bounds of the next maze? Or is it possible to make an array from the different 'bounds'?

```
    stop();
var isRight:Boolean=false;
var isLeft:Boolean=false;
var isUp:Boolean=false;
var isDown:Boolean=false;
var speed:int = 10;

var mazeRect:Rectangle = bounds.getBounds(this);
var charRect:Rectangle = char.getBounds(this);
var boundsBmpData = new BitmapData(mazeRect.width, mazeRect.height, true, 0);
var charBmpData = new BitmapData(charRect.width, charRect.height, true, 0);

boundsBmpData.draw(bounds);
charBmpData.draw(char);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moving);



    function keyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
        {
             if(event.keyCode==39){
             isRight=true}
             if(event.keyCode==37){
             isLeft=true}
             if(event.keyCode==38){
             isUp=true}
             if(event.keyCode==40){
             isDown=true}
        }

    function keyReleased(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
             if(event.keyCode==39){
             isRight=false}
             if(event.keyCode==37){
             isLeft=false}
             if(event.keyCode==38){
             isUp=false}
             if(event.keyCode==40){
             isDown=false}
        }



    function moving(e: Event): void
        {
              var newx: Number = char.x - (isLeft ? speed : 0) + (isRight ? speed : 0);
              var newy: Number = char.y - (isUp ? speed : 0) + (isDown ? speed : 0);
              if(!boundsBmpData.hitTest(new Point(bounds.x, bounds.y),
                                        255,
                                        charBmpData,
                                        new Point(newx, newy),
                                        255))
              {
                 char.x = newx;
                 char.y = newy;
              }

                 if(char.hitTestObject(door))
                        { 
                        onHitTest();
                        }

        }

    function onHitTest() : void
        {
            nextFrame();

        }
```

Comment: I am not sure how you have your FLA file set up.  It's a bit hard to tell what's going on without seeing the timeline and the `bounds` and `door` objects.

Comment: @iND I'm working on the timeline(actions), first frame movieclips: character, bounds and door. Draws the bitmap of the character and the bounds. Second frame is the same except it should draw a new bitmap for the new bounds. If it's possible I could upload the FLA?

Comment: You can put a link to the FLA file.  Otherwise, you email it to my junk email: testdee@yahoo.com.

Comment: @iND thank you, I've send you the FLA file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the FLA, there were a few issues.

- the main one is that though you switched frames, you did not reset your pointers to the `bounds` object, the `door` object, and the `char` object.  So you were still tied to the old ones programmatically, though not visually.

  - I put the declarations into a method called `setupFrame()`, and call it from your `onHitTest()` method.
- I added a check in `onHitTest()` to make sure that the `bounds` object exists in the current frame before setting up the frame.  If not, the game stops.
- The actions and char layers now extend across the entire game timeline, since they are reused.
- `char` object is now repositioned each frame using points found in the `startPts` array, instead of having to recreate it each time.
- removed the event listeners during the frame setup, and add them at the end of the frame setup.  This prevents possible errors from listening to the events.

This is a pretty good effort at creating a simple game engine.  Just fyi, [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) is a place devoted to all levels of game development, and you can ask more theoretical questions there.

HTH!

Comment: Realy helpful, thank you so much for your time! Also clear explanation and thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try calling dispose() on old BitmapData first and then create new one?

Comment: This assumes no reuse of the images, like for "playback" features, or for saving particularly good random mazes, or whatever.  I think more clarity on the process and goals are needed.

Comment: True. Would be nice to see fla + problem causing part to figure out what's the problem.